# (node:23468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am facing an issue using node.js and mongoose, when I am trying to run the following query I get this error. I tried almost every possible solution but nothing helped out.
my mongo DB version is 5.0.6, node.js is v14.17.1 and the mongoose version is ^6.0.10

```
const getConversationsToJoin = async(userId) => {
    const conversations = await Conversation.find({ status: 'active' }, {
        $or: [{
                member_a_id: userId
            },
            {
                member_b_id: userId
            }
        ]
    });
    return conversations
}
```

> (node:23468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or
> $setField.
> at MessageStream.messageHandler (D:\laragon\www\Tuxedo_API\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:467:30)
> at MessageStream.emit (events.js:375:28)
> at processIncomingData (D:\laragon\www\Tuxedo_API\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
> at MessageStream._write (D:\laragon\www\Tuxedo_API\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
> at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
> at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
> at Socket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:726:22)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)
> at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
> at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:23468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:23468) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is nothing related to the version of technologies used, it's an incorrect use of `find` query. Find query will only take one argument, that is supposed to contain all your filters.

Moreover the syntax for $or is incorrect too. It should not be wrapped inside curly braces.

Here is what you should be doing:

```
const getConversationsToJoin = async (userId) => {
  const conversations = await Conversation.find({
    status: "active",
    $or: [
      {
        member_a_id: userId,
      },
      {
        member_b_id: userId,
      },
    ],
  });
  return conversations;
};
```